# How to connect to Office 365 with PHPMailer?

Tags: office365, phpmailer, office365connectors

I have a problem with PHPMailer, I want to connect to a Office 365 server which is configured with my website IP, there is made a connector so I can connect to the Office 365 SMTP server to connect without authentication because my IP address is whitelisted.

The problem is that I can not authenticate to the server.

PHPMailer output:

```
2016-11-23 09:06:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.thuis*******.nl 2016-11-23 09:06:50  SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2016-11-23 09:06:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2016-11-23 09:06:50  SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

PHP File:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->Host = "thuis*******-nl.mail.protection.outlook.com";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SetFrom('john@thuis*******.nl', 'John');
$mail->AddReplyTo("noreply@thuis*******.nl");
$mail->Subject = "This is the subject";
$mail->MsgHTML('Message body');
$address = "john@doe.nl";
$mail->AddAddress($address);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
   echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete example, so make sure you're using the latest version. It would also help if you read the documentation the error message points you at.

Comment: @Synchro Thank you, I have found the solution, you can read it below.

Answer (score 1):

Set `SMTPAuth` to `false`:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
```

**Reason:** my server does not have any email accounts configured.

The server IP address is whitelisted to send mail from any mail address with `@thuis*******.nl`.